# How to get out of the following enumerate python program as a List

Tags: python

```
for i,x in enumerate(['A','B','C']):
    print(i, x)
```

Current output is:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

I need the output to be as `[(0,A), (1,B), (2,C)]`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a call to [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
out = list(enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C')]
```

Comment: I see ;) Now our answers are identical thought :p

Comment: Who cares? Let's see which one the OP accepts ;)

Comment: Doesn't matter. I'm wondering what is the use case though because of the `print`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the `enumerate` iterator to a list:

```
out = list(enumerate(['A','B','C']))
```

Output:`[(0,A), (1,B), (2,C)]` (the output is a list object)

If you just want to print:

```
print(list(enumerate(['A','B','C'])))
```

Finally, if you're looking to build a string with your specific format, use:

```
print('[%s]' % ','.join(f'({i},{v})' for i,v in enumerate(['A','B','C'])))
```

Output: `'[(0,A),(1,B),(2,C)]'`

Comment: Nitpick, `enumerate` objects are not generators, although, they are iterators

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks fixed ;)